# Wordpress Custom Meta Box Update Template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

So I have created a custom plugin to add another meta box of which will control the page template. The code functions perfectly fine if you only have 1 page with the set value.

Example:
1 Page has radio button 2 selected (works fine)
2 Pages have radio button 2 selected (The first page will work fine the 2nd page will default to the page.php default file.)

Any Ideas as to why it will select the different template value for one page but then for all others defaults back to the page.php template?

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Wireframe Templates For Pages V3.7
* Description: Adds a wireframe selection section for the page template
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Daniel Vickers
*/

// Dont call me direct!
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;


// Create content
function custom_meta_box_markup($object)
{
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");

    ?>

<style>
label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
  visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
  position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}
label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
label > input:checked + img{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
</style>



        <div>

            <h4>Radio options</h4>
            <?php
                // U need to use this to set the checked="checked"
                $checkbox_value = get_post_meta($object->ID, "page-template-radio", true);
            ?>
                       <label>
                       <input type="radio" name="page-template-radio" value="default"<?php if($checkbox_value == 'default'){echo 'checked =\"checked\"';} ?> /><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x220"></label>
                       <label>
                       <input type="radio" name="page-template-radio" value="2col" <?php if($checkbox_value == '2col'){echo 'checked =\"checked\"';} ?>/><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x220"></label>
                       <label>
                       <input type="radio" name="page-template-radio" value="1col" <?php if($checkbox_value == '1col'){echo 'checked =\"checked\"';} ?>/>
                       <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x220">
                       </label>

        </div>
<?php
}


// Saving data
function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $slug = "post";
    if($slug != $post->post_type)
        return $post_id;



    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-radio"]))
    {
        $meta_box_value = $_POST["meta-box-radio"];
    }
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-radio", $meta_box_value);

}

add_action("save_post", "save_custom_meta_box", 10, 3);


function add_custom_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Page Template", "custom_meta_box_markup", "page", "normal", "high", null);
}

add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");

// Get our option for post ID from the options meta box change "$field_name" to your option name you use in the meta box
$post_option = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),"page-template-radio",true);

// Check our option and change the display to what option is set

    if($post_option == "default")
    {
        update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page.php' );
   }
    elseif($post_option == "2col") {
        update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page-2col.php' );
    }
    elseif ($post_option == "1col") {
        update_post_meta( $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page-1col.php' );
    }
    else{
     // Added for when an option is not set
    }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks a bit like a mess, but I think I see the problem.
You're saving the value in a different meta property than you're getting the value from.

In the edit screen you can also open the 'extra fields' item. That would show you all the meta data for a post and is a great help for diagnosing problems with saving meta.

You can also have a look at https://github.com/svrooij/wp-geocoded-posts/blob/master/geocoded-posts/includes/class-geocoded-posts-editor.php this is the class of my plugin, for adding some meta fields to a post. It's getting loaded by the plugin file a folder higher.